# Angular + Spring Boot. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con angular + spring boot. Y me da el error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. A veces me sale este otro error: GET http://localhost:8090/api/employees net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, Dependiendo de si inicio angular con ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json o con ng serve a secas.

Mi controlador de Spring boot es el siguiente.

```
package com.test.mainApp.controller;

import com.test.mainApp.entity.Employee;
import com.test.mainApp.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

 EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


 //@RequestMapping(value="/employees", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 @GetMapping("/employees")
 public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
     return (List)employeeRepository.findAll();
 }

 //@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{job}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 @GetMapping("/employees/{job}")
 public List<Employee> getEmployeesByJob(@PathVariable String job){
     return (List)employeeRepository.findByJob(job);
 }

 //@RequestMapping(value="/employees/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
 @DeleteMapping("/emloyees/{id}")
 public boolean deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id){
     Optional<Employee> dbEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
     if(dbEmployee.isPresent()) {
         Employee existingEmployee = dbEmployee.get();
         employeeRepository.delete(existingEmployee);
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

}

Mi componente para listar los empleados es este:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Employee } from '../../entities/employee';
import { EmployeeServiceService } from '../../services/employee-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-employee',
  templateUrl: './list-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-employee.component.css']
})
export class ListEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Array<Employee>;

  constructor(private emploService: EmployeeServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emploService.getAllEmployees()
    .subscribe(response => this.employees = response), (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");
        }
});
```

}

}

Mi Servicio de angular es este:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from '../entities/employee';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  private url:string="http://localhost:8090/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getAllEmployees(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"/employees");
  }


}
```

Añadir que tengo el proyecto de angular dentro de ~/NetBeansProjects/MyFirstApp/src/main/resources/static/crud-employees-client (Sí, estoy en Linux. Point Linux, más concretamente).
Con Spring Initializr he añadido las dependencias Web, JPA y H2.
En consola, también me aparece "Server-side error occured.", que es el error que he capturado y he obtenido información gracias al HttpErrorResponse.

Si necesitáis algún dato más, decid. Gracias de antemano.

---

Edit:

El error es:
GET http://localhost:8090/api/employees net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:2969
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:407
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @   zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone    @   zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @   zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function)  @   zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @   http.js:1639
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:28
(anonymous) @   subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult   @   subscribeToResult.js:6
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub  @   mergeMap.js:70
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext   @   mergeMap.js:67
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next  @   mergeMap.js:50
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @   scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @   mergeMap.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:23
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @   filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:23
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call   @   map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:23
push../src/app/components/list-employee/list-employee.component.ts.ListEmployeeComponent.ngOnInit   @   list-employee.component.ts:20
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline   @   core.js:9248
checkAndUpdateNodeInline    @   core.js:10512
checkAndUpdateNode  @   core.js:10474
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @   core.js:11107
debugCheckDirectivesFn  @   core.js:11067
(anonymous) @   ListEmployeeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js [sm]:1
debugUpdateDirectives   @   core.js:11059
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10456
callViewAction  @   core.js:10697
execEmbeddedViewsAction @   core.js:10660
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10457
callViewAction  @   core.js:10697
execComponentViewsAction    @   core.js:10639
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10462
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:11349
debugCheckAndUpdateView @   core.js:11027
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges  @   core.js:8843
(anonymous) @   core.js:4579
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @   core.js:4579
(anonymous) @   core.js:4471
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:388
onInvoke    @   core.js:3822
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run   @   zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run  @   core.js:3736
next    @   core.js:4471
schedulerFn @   core.js:3553
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub   @   Subscriber.js:195
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:133
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next  @   Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @   Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit   @   core.js:3537
checkStable @   core.js:3791
onHasTask   @   core.js:3835
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask   @   zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue

Edit2:
Estoy en otro PC, lo he probado y he conseguido que sólo el Spring Boot me imprima Hello world, en http://localhost:8080/api/test. Pero cuando lo combino con Angular y éste tiene que obtener los datos del servidor, falla. Me sale en firefox: Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:8080/api/test. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).
Y en Chrome me sigue saliendo el mismo error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Y se supone que añadiendo @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200") encima del controlador debería ir, pero no es así.

---

Edit3:
He creado una clase para evitar el problema con CORS. La clase es la siguiente:

```
package com.test.mainApp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/test").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Ahora me sale en firefox:

```
Object { headers: Object, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown …", error: error }
```

Y en chromium: "Error HttpErrorResponse", aparte del "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED."
Y en chromium: "Error HttpErrorResponse", aparte del "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED."

Cuando printo el error en formato string, me aparece [ object Object ]

Comment: puedes poner el error completo porfavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he dado con la  solución. Fallaban varias cosas. En primer lugar, me faltaba una anotación @Autowired en el Controlador:

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
```

Luego, en vez de `EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository` he puesto `EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>` para asegurarme que el `employeeRepository.findAll()` devolviese una Lista y no un Iterable.

Para seguir, he cambiado la estructura de las carpetas. El proyecto de spring lo tenia dentro de proyecto/server y la parte de angular en proyecto/client. Esto es importante porque así puedes abrir por un lado el servidor en Eclipse/Netbeans y por otro en una terminal el angular. De la forma en la que lo tenía antes, no funcionaba.

Y por último, sé que es una chorrada, pero me explicaré: iniciaba sólo el cliente, en vez del cliente y el servidor, porque en uno de mis pcs cuando lo hacia se quedaba congelado. Cambié de pc a uno más potente, y ya iba.

Answer (score 0):

En tu servicio Angular has declarado

`private url:string="http://localhost:8090/api";`

pero dado que no has incluido ni indicado nada respecto a la configuración que usas para Spring Boot, ¿estás seguro que ese es el puerto correcto? Por defecto, la aplicación SB escuchará en el 8080 y no en ese 8090, lo que explicaría que te de ese error.

Comment: En el archivo de application.properties de Spring Boot tengo puesto: server.port=8090

Comment: Ok. Aún y así te has asegurado que realmente esté escuchando en ese puerto? Has probado a crear un endpoint simple que te devuelva un "hello world", por ejemplo, y a invocarlo desde el navegador con una URL tipo http://localhost:8090/api/test ?

Comment: Con anterioridad probé el puerto 8080 y me salía el mismo error. Lo que pasa que cambié el puerto para que no entrase en conflicto con el Tomcat. He probado lo que me dices, de intentar printar un hello world y me sale el mismo error: (1) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. (2) ERROR HttpErrorResponse defaultErrorLogger.

Comment: Cuando estaba desarrollando la parte de Java Spring abrí la consola de h2 e hice un select de unos valores que se introducen en la db al iniciar la aplicación, y me salían los valores insertados. Eso si, cuando accedía a: http://localhost:8080/api/employees (antes lo tenia en el puerto 8080), me salía el Whitelabel error page, en vez de los valores de los empleados insertados.

Comment: Si uso http://localhost:8080/api/test me sale este error: (1)GET http://localhost:8080/api/test net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. (2)ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false…}

Comment: Pues ahora mismo sólo se me ocurren dos cosas: que tengas algún firewall que te esté capando el acceso o que esa anotación @CrossOrigin esté teniendo implicaciones no previstas, aunque me suena muy raro